# Why does this phrase use 似的 instead of 似地？

Tags: word-choice

在他脑海中幻灯似的循环浮现

I think that 循环浮现 is a verb-phrase, right?
In which case I would expect to see 似地 instead of 似的.

Can someone explain this and provide a sample translation for the example sentence? Thanks!

Comment: 地 seems possible see jukuu：3.  Blood was pumping out of his belly like a fountain.
 血像喷泉似地从他的腹部涌出。
 
7.  He was miraculously healed of cancer.
 他的癌症被奇迹似地治愈。 
and many more examples

Comment: 似的 shìde：＂汉语水平考试词典＂：表示比喻，常跟＂像、跟、仿佛＂等配合，意思是在某一方面类似于某物（as；like）：他走路跟猴子～一蹦一跳｜姑娘像仙女～漂亮。
bkrs：seems as if，rather like，Taiwan pr. [sì de]
regarding descriptive use of 的 in general：＂实用现代汉语语法＂p。３５７：用在名词短语、形容词短语或包含形容词的名词短语后，描写一种状态。例如：（４）小路坑坑洼洼的，很难走。（５）孩子们有说有笑的，很高兴。（６）地里的麦苗绿油油的，很惹人爱。（７）外面黑灯瞎火的，我一个人不赶出去。（８）屋子里乱七八糟的，好像没有人住。
p.511:＂（像）。。。似地＂因已包含＂地＂，所以后面不用＂地＂，＂（像）。。。一样＂后可以用＂地＂也可以不用＂地＂。例如：（１）我麻木了似地望着门。（２）小红像小鸟一样（地）飞回了家。jukuu has many examples with 似地，are these pronounced side or shìde？

Comment: user just came across another example of 似地 in the translation "肠子＂of Palahniuks novel "Haunted" 
http://99lib.net/book/2860/88375.htm  梳在一旁的灰发，直直地垂落下来，像穗子似地挂在有老人斑的光头四周。His gray comb-over hairs, hanging straight down, fringe around the sides of his spotted bald head.

Comment: Interesting... It looks like 似地 is used sometimes with a similar meaning to 似的. How perfectly confusing :P

Comment: @sazarando, as in my answer, there is no "似地" in the Chinese dictionary (e.g. 新华字典 or 现代汉语词典). All the usage you see for "似地" can/should be replaced by "似的".

Comment: I understand that "似地" not in 汉语（字词）典 as a 熟語, but it does seem to be mentioned as a possible correct usage in this Japanese<>Chinese dictionary http://cjjc.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BC%BC%E7%9A%84 and also in this Chinese<>English dictionary http://dict.cn/%E4%BC%BC%E5%9C%B0 and is also listed in many example sentences for this Chinese<>English dictionary http://ce.linedict.com/dict.html#/cnen/example?query=%E4%BC%BC%E5%9C%B0

Comment: @sazarando. Yeah, although "as well" is always two words, you can see "aswell" being used in many places. It doesn't mean "aswell" is correct.

Comment: @Bolu I understand what you're saying, but the links I shared were to dictionary entries, not just random source material. Do you have any thoughts on why 似地 appears in the sources I quoted above? I don't mean to nitpick, I'm just curious if I'm missing something here.

Comment: @sazarando, Those are for historical reasons, based on the latest version of the official Chinese dictionary, the correct usage is "似的". If you use website that based on the latest official dictionaries, you won't find any "似地". e.g. http://cidian.xpcha.com/.  And [here are some detailed explanations](http://www.pep.com.cn/xiaoyu/jiaoshi/study/jszy/yy/bzxc/201012/t20101202_980614.htm). It is from 人民教育出版社 "People's Education Press(PEP)". The summary is in its last sentence: *"无论什么情况，都不应将“似的”写作“似地”."*, which means *"No matter in what circumstance, you should only use “似的” rather than “似地”"*.

Comment: @Bolu Dude, that is a great link. 太谢谢你了！The comparision with 真的 makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"似的" is a fixed term/word, there is no "似地", so no matter how/where you use it (eg. after a verb or noun), the expression is always "似的".

You can still see "似地" in many places nowadays is mainly due to historical reasons. However based on the latest version of the official Chinese dictionary, the correct usage is alwyas "似的". If you use website that based on the latest official dictionaries, you won't find any "似地". e.g. [cidian.xpcha.com](http://cidian.xpcha.com)

[Here are some detailed explanations.](http://www.pep.com.cn/xiaoyu/jiaoshi/study/jszy/yy/bzxc/201012/t20101202_980614.htm) It is from 人民教育出版社 "People's Education Press(PEP)", the official publisher of the Chinese Dictionaries used in Mainland. The summary is in its last sentence: **"无论什么情况，都不应将“似的”写作“似地”."**, which means **"No matter in what circumstance, you should only use “似的” rather than “似地”"**.

One more quoted paragraph for the comment below:

> 虽然也有一些语法书、辞书，如黄伯荣、廖序东主编的《现代汉语》(甘肃人民教育出版社1983年版)、王自强编著的《现代汉语虚词用法小词典》(上海辞书出版社1984年版)等有“似的”组成短语作状语时可写作“似地”的说法，但一般的现代汉语词典特别是权威性词典，都不收录“似地”这种写法，这在实际上是以“似的”为规范词形，而弃置“似地”这一写法。

Comment: dictionaries distinguish between 似 shì as part of 似的 and 似 si，the entry for the latter being much longer, users may be forced to conclude therefore that the examples with 似地 in jukuu and 实用现代汉语语法 （see above comments）are pronounced side

Comment: @user6065, as in my answer, there is no "似地" in the Chinese dictionary.

Comment: @user6065, Edited in my comments to OP, just in case if you've missed it.

Comment: Quoted article starts with: “似的”，音de，也作“是的”, there has never been any question about 似的 shìde, and e.g. 现代汉语词典 （１９９８）has 似shì only as part of 似的, whereas the entry for 似 read "si" is considerably longer and has 3 sub-entries, users might conclude that the since ２００７ supposedly wrong instances of 似地 are read "side". According to ＂实用现代汉语语法＂（２００１北京) p.514 似地 was still correct in 2001 and for "似地" jukuu supplies the maximum number 100 of examples  all containing "似地" with nothing in between.

Comment: @user6065, you are correct by saying "似" can read both "shi" or "si". But there is still only one correct use which is "似的" ("shi""de"), there is no "si""de" by read or "似地" by write. Jukuu is not official, can make mistake. and you quoted ＂实用现代汉语语法＂（２００１北京) is not official as well. See my updated answer for more detail.

Comment: jukuu seems to show that a very reasonable recommendation by public education professionals is not yet being followed by most writers

不过句酷似乎表明的是，大多数的作者还不遵循着公立教育某传家的很有道理的一个建议

Comment: @user6065, what did you mean? what is the recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

Because "似的" is a single word and it does not modify "循环浮现"! It is different from those adverbs or adverbial phrases that modifies the succeeding verb directly.

"像……似的" or "……似的" itself is a complete adverbial phrase. You can replace this part with "像……一样".

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me! Can you provide a translation for the sentence in the OP?

Comment: 在他脑海中幻灯似的循环浮现，continued to pass through (appeared again and again in) his mind like slides (of a slide show)