# Use of 真的 as adverb: are 我真要走了 and 我真的要走了 equally correct?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I came across the sentence: "我真的要走了".

I am wondering why it has the 的. I didn't know 真 needed a 的 to be an adverb, or that it was even ok.

Is it equally correct to say "我真要走了"? Or is "我真的要走了" better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"我真要走了" and "我真的要走了" are both good expressions. They are in fact no different at all. "真" and "真的" are both adverbs here.

Comment: also see Q regarding whether 似的 or 似地, http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/19376/why-does-this-phrase-use-%E4%BC%BC%E7%9A%84-instead-of-%E4%BC%BC%E5%9C%B0

Answer (score 0):

From the Taiwanese Ministry of Education dictionary [教育部國語辭典簡編本](http://dict.concised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/jbdic/gsweb.cgi?ccd=SX_XuY&o=e0&sec=sec1&op=v&view=0-1)

的 has 5 usages:

1. Particle after adjective.

   e.g. 美麗 (beautiful) **的** 風景 (scenary)
2. Possessive pronoun, placed after a noun or pronoun.

   e.g. 我 (my) **的** 書 (book)
3. Particle after a modifier phrase or clause.

   e.g. 他寄來 (which he had sent) **的** 信 (The letter)，我已經在昨天收到了 (I received yesterday)。
4. Placed after adverb. Same as "地".

   e.g. 慢慢 (slowly) **的** 走 (walk)
5. Placed after sentence, to show confidence or strengthen the tone.

   e.g. 你這樣做是不可以 (you should not be doing this) **的**！

In Chinese grammar, 1. and 3. forms the **Modifier-Head** construct, in that an adjective-acting piece of text is used to describe a noun-acting word or phrase.

And 4. forms the **Adverbial-Head** construct, in that an adverb-acting word or phrase is used to describe a verb-acting word or phrase.